# How To convert int into NSDate format?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have taken two values like 140 & 200 , now if i add 140+200 = 340 i want the output of 340 days into NSDate format

Comment: Do you want to convert to NSDate format? or NSData format?

Answer (score 2):

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
NSDateComponents *components = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
[components setDay:340];

NSDate *date = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
```

Gives you a date for the 340s day of year 0... That was really long ago.

Comment: ok and if i have particular date like 1/july/2012 and if i add 365 days than can i get output like 1/july/2013 if yes then give me the answer

Comment: @Bhavika That wasn't your question, but anyway: Its the same principal, get the `NSDateComponents` of your starting `NSDate` (can be obtained from the `NSCalendar` and add 365 to its days. Not though that 365 days aren't necessarily a year! If you want to add one year exactly, add 1 to the year of the date components!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to add 340 days to today

```
   NSTimeIntervall timeToAddInDays = 60 * 60 * 24 * 340;
   NSDate *theFutureDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:timeToAddInDays];
```

But be aware - as JustSid mentionend below - this is adding exactly 340 days - this is maybe not war you want/need.